# How to route a custom bottom navigator?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to route a custom navigator if there is no routing? I tried many alternatives but I can t route both buttons. Only the HomePage worked.

The code is below:

```
    BottomNavigationBarItem _bottomIcons(IconData icon) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(icon), title: Text(""));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: LightColor.purple,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: LightColor.extraDarkPurple,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: 1,
          items: [
            _bottomIcons(Icons.home),
            _bottomIcons(Icons.arrow_back_ios),

          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HomePage(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using if condition based on the index value to navigate to two different pages using routes. Try the below mentioned code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyButton(),
  ));
}

class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyButtonState createState() {
    return MyButtonState();
  }
}

class MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
   BottomNavigationBarItem _bottomIcons(IconData icon) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(icon), title: Text(""));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: 1,
          items: [
            _bottomIcons(Icons.home),
            _bottomIcons(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            if(index == 0){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          ),
        );
            }
            else if(index == 1){
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
          ),
        );
            }
          },
        ),
      );
      }
}
```

Happy coding!!!

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thank you very much for your time :)